# Subtracting time PHP

Tags: php, html, date, strtotime

I am having trouble with subtracting times in PHP.

My times are:

**$row['exp']** = 2017-03-31

**and date('Y-m-d')** = 2017-03-10 (today)

```
$datetime1 = strtotime($row['exp']);
$datetime2 = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
$secs = $datetime1 - $datetime2;// == <seconds between the two times>
$days = $secs / 86400;
echo $days;
```

My result is:

> 36520.958333333333

Comment: Besides the answer below id also look into "Carbon" if your going to be dealing allot with time and dates - http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: @keaner Thank you, that's interesting!

Comment: no problem i use it allot and it works wonders

Comment: Before you post a question called **Subtracting time PHP**.  You should search for those keywords in SO's search box (if not a major search engine).  There are **pages** and **pages** of results at http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Subtracting+time+PHP  Please do your research before posting a new question because, chances are, someone has already asked it and answered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the PHP DateTime class instead, it has built in functions, such as DateTime::diff, which seems to be what you're looking for. The DateTime objects are much easier to work with too.

```
$today = new DateTime('today');
$date = new DateTime("2017-03-31");

echo $today->diff($date)->d; // 21
```

Just pass your `$row['exp']` as the parameter of `$date` instead, so you get

```
$date = new DateTime($row['exp']);
```

---

Although, I can't reproduce your issue with the given input you have, [this live demo](https://3v4l.org/48LZa) outputs "20.958333333333" (which is about right, you just need to `ceil()` it).

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/jvmYr)

## References

- http://php.net/datetime.diff

Comment: Yeah, this [**demo**](https://3v4l.org/48LZa) shows the expected result with your code, so I'm thinking maybe your `$row['exp']` isn't the value you think it is? I'd start looking at that, as the code and information you've supplied so far, works.

Comment: By the way, your answer doesn't work if the date is exactly 1 year later.

Comment: That's because the offset in days is 0, but the offset in year is 1. If you do `$today->diff($date)->format('%a days');` you should get the expected result.